# Xcode failed build - confused as to interpretation

Tags: ios, xcode

My app now fails to build in Xcode 5, but I have no idea why I suddenly have duplicate symbols for one of the architectures:

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation) 255 duplicate symbols for architecture arm7

I had changed code signing identities for distribution to test devices, but have changed them back, and now this.

As an example case, one of the errors is as follows:

> duplicate symbol _kAccompanyingTextPlaceHolder in:
>       /Users/.../i386/Record.o
>       /Users/.../i386/PickerVC.o

Can anyone explain this? Is there something I am likely to have incorrectly reset when switching back to development?

Comment: have you integrate any new libraries or sources into your project? also there might be duplicated constants in your sources? can you put detailed error here.

Comment: Show at least a few of the 255 duplicate symbols. Wondering why we have to ask for the error messages so often.

Comment: No, there is no new code, libraries or anything. I have been playing with Xcode 6, but haven't touched this project.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution: Just roll back to the working version in the project source control (Git probably). Or even TimeMachine.

The error says that two .o files have the same symbol: `_kAccompanyingTextPlaceHolder`.

The two object files are: `Record.o` and `PickerVC.o`. There must be two source files with similar names, remove one from the project.

Or both of the two files have `_kAccompanyingTextPlaceHolder` in the same scope.

Or something else.

In any event it is clear what the conflicts are, resolve them.

Comment: I ended up resorting to a snapshot, but I'm none the wiser as to what the problem was. Same code, problem disappears, no explanation.